# Dashboard edit issue in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

In Salesforce, if a user creates a dashboard, he gets edit access. But if the admin created the dashboard and gave it to a user but he does not get edit access, is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Someone with administrative privileges would need to change the share settings of the dashboard to give the user edit access. Depending on the circumstances, another option could be to clone the dashboard.

Note: You will likely still need access to, maybe edit access to, underlying reports as well.

If this doesn't help, will you provide more details about your circumstance?